# Doctrine: Set model values as array

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I've got an array of values I want to update my model with.

Doctrine_Access provides a function setArray which is nearly exactly what I need - except it cares about values that don't have fields in the model. I want those to be ignored.

A little example. Say we have a User table with the field username.

```
$user = new User();
$user->setArray(array('username'=>'xyz'))->save();
```

That would work!

```
$user = new User();
$user->setArray(array('username'=>'xyz','anotherKey'=>'anotherValue'))->save();
```

That doesn't. I want Doctrine to just ignore anotherKey, if there is no related field. 
The intention is, that I don't want to filter my arrays before I update my model.

What is the cleanest and easiest way to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine_Record::fromArray() solves it. 
Unfortunately it doesn't return the object, so it's useless for method chaining...

Answer (score -1):

this is useful

add find method to model:

```
class Address extends Doctrine_Record {

    public static function factory() {
        return new Address();
    }

public function findById($id) {
       $findObject = Doctrine::getTable('Address')->findOneByid($id);
       return $findObject;
     }
....
```

and use it

```
  $address = Address::factory()
        ->findById(13)->set('name', 'new data')->set('anotherfield','another data')->save();
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. He is trying to create a new record, instantiating the model and setting the values from an array. You didn't give him any way near to that. Sorry for down vote, gotta let others know this isn't a useful answer.